# How can I make a counter counting down from 25 by keeping only the seconds in the database with php?

Tags: javascript, php

I made a counter counting down from 25 with javscript, but when different users request the page, different time values ​​are displayed in the counter. Instead, I want to keep those 25 seconds in the database and count down with php or javascript so that every user sees the same value. How can I set up logic for the database?After 25 seconds it has to start again

```
var interval = 25000; 

      function reset() {
        localStorage.endTime = +new Date() + interval;
      }

      if (!localStorage.endTime) {
        reset();
      }
      function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
        var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
        return (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
       }
      setInterval(function () {
        var remaining = localStorage.endTime - new Date();
        if (remaining >= 0) {
          document.getElementById("timer").innerText =
            millisToMinutesAndSeconds(remaining);
        } else {
          tensecond();
        }
      }, 100);


var interval10 = 10000; 
    
          function reset() {
            localStorage.endTime = +new Date() + interval10;
          }
    
          if (!localStorage.endTime) {
            reset();
          }
          function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
            var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
            return (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
           }
          setInterval(function () {
            var remaining10 = localStorage.endTime - new Date();
            if (remaining10 > 0) {
              document.getElementById("timer").innerText =
                millisToMinutesAndSeconds(remaining10);
            } else {
              reset();
            }
          }, 100);
```

Comment: Any reason not to just use `Date.now()` to synchronize the counters and avoid php and databases entirely?

Comment: I haven't tried it but the problem seems to be using javascript. Think of it this way, I logged into the page, the counter counts down from 12, but when someone else logs in at the same time, it counts from 19, so I thought of keeping it in the database to ensure that everyone sees the same counter value, but I don't know how to do that. @RockySims

Answer (score 1):

I would probably instead store the end time of the timer (in UTC) in the database.  Then, your clients can do something like:

```
const startTimer = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://your-server/timer');
    const endTime = await response.json(); // ex: { timestamp: 1663088872145 }
    const end = newDate(endTime.timestamp);
    const i = setInterval(() => { 
        const seconds = ((new Date()).valueOf() - end.valueOf()) / 1000
        if (i >= 0) {
            document.getElementById('timer').html = seconds;
        } else {
            clearInterval(i);
        }
    });
}
```

For example (with a mock backend):

```js
const fetch = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve({
            json: async function() {
                return { timestamp: (new Date()).valueOf() + 15000 };
            }
        });
    });
}

const startTimer = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://your-server/timer');
    const endTime = await response.json(); // ex: { timestamp: 1663088872145 }
    const end = new Date(endTime.timestamp);
    let seconds = Math.round(-((new Date()).valueOf() - end.valueOf()) / 1000)
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = seconds;
    const i = setInterval(() => { 
        seconds = Math.round(-((new Date()).valueOf() - end.valueOf()) / 1000)
        if (seconds >= 0) {
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = seconds;
        } else {
            clearInterval(i);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```

```html
<div id="timer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using php and a database which should ensure that multiple users loading the page at different times all see the same value for the count down.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const timerMs = 25000 - (Date.now() % 25000);
  document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = millisToSeconds(timerMs);
}, 100);

function millisToSeconds(millis) {
  const seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
  return (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
}
```

Comment: thank you teacher. To make it count down from 25 25000 -Date.now() 25000%; do i do enough? @RockySims

Comment: I've updated it to count down. Basically just changed `Date.now() % 25000` to `25000 - (Date.now() % 25000)`

Comment: There is a problem here, sir. There is if, else in the function I wrote above. If 25 seconds were over, I would put it in a 10-second function, count down 10 seconds, and go back to 25 seconds. In the part of the code you added, it falls into the else condition many times and the problem arises. How can I solve this? @RockySims

Comment: So in the code I wrote, it drops to minus and the other function works immediately. @RockySims